# In Ubuntu, is there something I can run that checks the HTTP requests coming in?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, http, tcp

I'm running Node.js. But for some reason, requests are not being caught by the server. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247482/node-js-server-not-receiving-ajax-requests)

Is there any way to check if there's an HTTP request coming in? Ideally, I want to run something that will "listen" for HTTP request, and then prints them as they come in, along with the URl of that http request (if possible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard tool would just be to install and run [tcpdump](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/tcpdump).

A capture filter like this.  `tcpdump -qn -s 0 -A port 80` would capture and print the every packet destined for port 80 on that system.  See the man pages, tcpdump is extremely flexible.

Answer (score 3):

I like Zoredache's answer of tcpdump as it is really a standard tool, you can also try out `ngrep`.

First you install it with:

```
apt-get install ngrep
```

Then you can use it to filter network streams looking for certain keywords like `GET`.

```
ngrep -W byline 'GET' 'port 80'
```

- `-W byline` is here to make it look prettier
- `GET` is the keyword we are looking for
- `port 80` can be replaced with bpf expression (e.g. ones used with tcpdump)